# How do I use COMPUTE to create and calculate a series of values in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I need to compute 61 new variables using a simple math equation based on 4 sets of 61 existing variables. I know I can write 61 compute statements. Is there a more elegant way of creating these variables?  Here's how the 61 statements would look:

```
COMPUTE score_1 = factor_1 * (a_1 + b_1) + c_1.
...
COMPUTE score_61 = factor_61 * (a_61 + b_61) + c_61.
EXECUTE.
```

Thanks in advance.

`recode` accept to and numbers my new variables (`recode raw1 to raw61 (1=0) (2=1) into a_1 to a_61.`) Can I do the same here?

Comment: If @horace_vr's answer solves your problem please mark it as a solution (and consider upvoting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `do repeat` structure

```
DO REPEAT score=score_1 score_2 ... score_61
/factor = factor_1 factor_2 ... factor_61
/a=a_1 a_2 ... a_61
/b=b_1 b_2 ... b_61
/c=c_1 c_2 ... c_61.
COMPUTE score=factor*(a+b)+c.
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.
```

In the fortunate event that your variables are in set order (i.e. - all factors are consecutive, all a are consecutive, etc. you may reference them using`to` like this:

`/factor = factor_1 TO factor_61`

otherwise, you need to enumerate them one by one. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks.  It works if you add in the missing periods.  should read

Comment: DO REPEAT score=score_1 score_2...score_61
/factor = factor_1 factor_2...factor_61
/a=a_1...a_61
/b=b_1...b_61
/c=c_1...c_61 .
COMPUTE score=factor*(a+b)+c.
END REPEAT.
EXECUTE.

Comment: right, edited, thank you! too much python for me lately :) Please accept the answer as correct, if it answers your question